# Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake. for get data with http client and server

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

Client side code with angular 4:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080').subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
    });
```

Server Side Code getting data from mysql:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "root",
        database: "mydb"
    });

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        con.connect(function(err) {
            if (err){
                res.write(err);
                res.end();
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                con.query("SELECT * FROM minister", function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.write(err);
                        res.end();
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
                        res.end();
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    }).listen(8080);
```

Getting data on localhost:8080 in browser but not sending data to html client site any on can help me? any thing wrong in my code